# React bootstrap image and fontawesome close toghether

Tags: reactjs

I have a component:

```
<Row>
            <Col xs={10}></Col>
            <Col xs="auto">
                <OverlayTrigger
                    placement="right"
                    delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
                    overlay={backwards}
                ><Image width="25%" height="25%" src="/assets/cofnij.jpg" thumbnail onClick={() => window.history.back()} />
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </Col>
            <Col xs="auto" >
                <OverlayTrigger
                    placement="right"
                    delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
                    overlay={backToMain}
                >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                        onClick={() => history.push("/")}
                        icon={faWindowClose} color="red" size='2x'
                    /></OverlayTrigger> </Col>

        </Row>
```

which produces me:
[image]

I tried to put them both in 1 column but then I see:
[image]

different sizes..
when I change size 3x for fontawesome I have:

[image]

looks like size is ok, but different Y ..
Dont know how to deal with that.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

put them in one column and add below classes in col

```
"d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
```

Comment: Do you know how to put them max to the right now ?

Comment: instead of justify-content-center add "justify-content-end"

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/ this will help you